# BorshDeserialize gives try_from_slice error

Tags: rust, deserialization, solana

I was exploring the **"BorshDeserialize"** option in Rust. and noticed the following issues when using trait bounds. Any help is appreciated

Sample code

```
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey;
use std::mem;

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct SampleData<'a> {
    accounts: (&'a Pubkey, &'a Pubkey),
    data: String,
    timestamp: u64,
    owner: &'a Pubkey,
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "Size of SampleData is {} bytes",
        mem::size_of::<SampleData>()
    );
    let _pub_key = Pubkey::default();
    let _a = SampleData {
        accounts: (&_pub_key, &_pub_key),
        data: "ABCDE".to_string(),
        timestamp: 1643116047,
        owner: &_pub_key,
    };
    let _encoded_a = _a.try_to_vec().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", _encoded_a);
    let _decoded_a = SampleData::try_from_slice(&_encoded_a).unwrap();
    println!("decoded_a: {:?}", _decoded_a);
}
```

---

Error message

> error[E0599]: the function or associated item `try_from_slice` exists
> for struct `SampleData<'_>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
> --> src/main.rs:27:34    | 6  | struct SampleData<'a> {    | ---------------------    | |    | function or associated item `try_from_slice` not found for this    | doesn't satisfy
> `SampleData<'_>: BorshDeserialize` ... 27 |     let _decoded_a =
> SampleData::try_from_slice(&_encoded_a).unwrap();    |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on
> `SampleData<'_>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds    | note: the
> following trait bounds were not satisfied because of the requirements
> of the implementation of `BorshDeserialize` for `_`:
> `(&Pubkey, &Pubkey): BorshDeserialize`
> `&Pubkey: BorshDeserialize`   --> src/main.rs:5:26    | 5  | #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 6  | struct SampleData<'a> {    |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    = help: items from traits can only be used if the
> trait is implemented and in scope    = note: the following trait
> defines an item `try_from_slice`, perhaps you need to implement it:
> candidate #1: `BorshDeserialize`    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `BorshDeserialize` (in Nightly builds,
> run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
> error: could not compile `seralize` due to previous error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SampleData` contains references, which isn't supported in normal Borsh deserialization.  Borsh creates a new instance of your type based on a slice, but it won't be able to create references.

If you want to stick with Borsh, you should change the type to:

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct SampleData {
    accounts: (Pubkey, Pubkey),
    data: String,
    timestamp: u64,
    owner: Pubkey,
}
```